# EC2 json template bash script not executing all of it

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have this part of my template:

```
            "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
              "sudo yum update -y\n",
              "sleep 30\n",
              "sudo mkdir /data \n",
              "cd /data/\n"
                  ]]}}
```

for the server.  It seems to execute the first line (since I can use wget) but doesn't do the 3rd or 4th lines.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-data is not run as a script unless the first two characters are `#!`

Try adding the following as the first line of the user-data so that CloudInit knows to run it as a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

As Rico points out, you can drop the `sudo` because [user-data scripts are run as root on the first boot of the instance](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts).

Also, the `sleep 30` and `cd /data/` are not providing any benefit if this is the entirety of the user-data script.

This would result in code like:

```
"UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
    "#!/bin/sh\n",
    "yum update -y\n",
    "mkdir /data \n",
]]}}
```

You could add the `cd` back in if there are further statements you are adding to the user-data script.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your */var/log/cloud-init.log* to see what's going on.   I don't think you need sudo since cloudinit stuff is run as root.

Also did you try:

```
"mkdir /data\n"
```

With no space between '/data' and '\n'?

Hope this helps.